# gradle install4 plugin how to specify license key

Tags: gradle, install4j

In the official documentation (http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html) I do not see a way of how to specify the license key, although there is a --license= flag. Anyone has any advice on how should this issue be solved?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 6.0.4, there is no way to set the license key with the gradle plugin, you would have to invoke

```
install4jc --license=[license key]
```

directly.

Comment: Any reasons for this?

Comment: When calling the command line compiler with the "-license" flag, it's currently not possible to specify a project or any other options. I've added this to our issue tracker to change this behavior for 6.1 and then the gradle ant and maven integrations will be able to set the license key directly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can set the license as follows

```groovy
install4j {
    installDir = file('/path/to/install4j_home')
    license = 'your_actual_license'
}
```

**Caution**: if the license property is specified, install4j will override any previous license and immediately exit. No installation files will be generated until the license configuration is removed.

See https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/help.pdf